# How to show $\Phi \cdot w = (\Phi^{-1})^* w$

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to prove $\Phi \cdot w = (\Phi^{-1})^* w$ to state some notation for $\Phi$ I just copy the problems in the textbook, Differential Geometry, Lie groups, and Symmetric Spaces by Sigurdur Helgason.

---

Let $\Phi$ be a diffeomorphism of a manifold $M$ onto itself. Then $\Phi$ induces a unique type-preserving automorphism $T \to \Phi \cdot T$ of the tensor algebra $D(M)$ such that :

(i) The automorphism commutes with contractions 
  (ii) $\Phi \cdot X = X^{\Phi}$, $(X\in D^1(M))$, $\Phi\cdot f = f^{\Phi},$ $(f \in C^{\infty}(M))$

Prove that $\Phi \cdot w = (\Phi^{-1})^* w$ for $w\in D_{*} (M)$

---

The solution in the textbooks are following

Let $w \in D_1(M)$. If $X \in  D^1(M)$ and $C$ is the contraction $X \otimes w \to w(X)$, then $\Phi \circ C = C \circ \Phi$ implies 
\begin{align}
   ( \Phi \cdot w)(X) = \Phi(w(X^{\Phi-1})) = ( ( \Phi^{-1})^* w)(X) 
\end{align}

---

I have trouble in understanding the last parts $\Phi \circ C = C \circ \Phi$  implies the above equation.

can you give me some detail reason for above process?